# GPS Location on custom map

Tags: iphone, ipad, gps

Is there a way to map the user's current location on an image view?

I have an map image of small area, and want to display the current location on it. Is there a way to calculate location on image from GPS coordinates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need lat/long references on the image to do it. Either two corners or edges. Then you interpolate the user coordinates onto the image using the references.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mean, all the lat/long references have to hard coded in? No way to calculate using a function or something?